# R Merge multiple dataframes by date, without repeating dates

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, merge, time-series

I have a two dataframes, they each contain a date column, and numeric value column. I want to merge by the data by date, such that I get 3 columns: a date and two respective values. When I merge these I end up with the dates repeated, and some seemingly random values thrown in. I have tried a few different merges (all=T, all.x=T etc.) as well as left_join, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

For now I am only merging two, but I do need to merge many of these tables, ending up with each date having many associated values.

```
> library(tidyverse)

> GR_Raw <- read.csv("Daily__Jul-16-2020_02_15_56AM.csv", sep = ",")
> names(GR_Raw)[1] <- "id"    
> GR_02GB001 <- filter(GR_Raw, id == "02GB001")
> GR_02GA003 <- filter(GR_Raw, id == "02GA003")
>
> GR_02GB001 <- data.frame(GR_02GB001$Date, GR_02GB001$Value)
> names(GR_02GB001) <- c("Date", "02GB001")
> 
> GR_02GA003 <- data.frame(GR_02GA003$Date, GR_02GA003$Value)
> names(GR_02GA003) <- c("Date","02GA003")

> GR_02GB001$Date <- as.Date(GR_02GB001$Date , format = "%Y/%m/%d")
> GR_02GA003$Date <- as.Date(GR_02GA003$Date , format = "%Y/%m/%d")

> GR_All <- merge(GR_02GB001, GR_02GA003, all=T)
> GR_Left <- left_join(GR_02GB001, GR_02GA003, by = "Date")
```

This is the resulting tables I get, note that there are no values over 10.000 in the two tables being merged.

```
> tail(GR_02GB001)
            Date 02GB001
45462 2019-12-26   0.386
45463 2019-12-27   0.398
45464 2019-12-28   0.459
45465 2019-12-29   0.593
45466 2019-12-30   0.805
45467 2019-12-31   1.095
> tail(GR_02GA003)
            Date 02GA003
45448 2019-12-26   0.802
45449 2019-12-27   0.817
45450 2019-12-28   0.899
45451 2019-12-29   0.943
45452 2019-12-30   1.279
45453 2019-12-31   1.461

> tail(GR_All)
            Date 02GB001 02GA003
58610 2019-12-30  95.600   1.279
58611 2019-12-30  95.600  74.800
58612 2019-12-31 143.000  97.500
58613 2019-12-31 143.000   1.461
58614 2019-12-31   1.095  97.500
58615 2019-12-31   1.095   1.461

> tail(GR_Left)
            Date 02GB001 02GA003
58610 2019-12-29   0.593  36.600
58611 2019-12-29   0.593   0.943
58612 2019-12-30   0.805  74.800
58613 2019-12-30   0.805   1.279
58614 2019-12-31   1.095  97.500
58615 2019-12-31   1.095   1.461



> str(GR_All)
'data.frame':   58615 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 38893 levels "1913-07-08","1913-07-09",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 02GB001: num  15.3 14.2 14.7 13.7 14.2 13.7 14.2 14 13 14.7 ...
 $ 02GA003: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> str(GR_02GB001)
'data.frame':   45467 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 38893 levels "1913-07-08","1913-07-09",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 02GB001: num  15.3 14.2 14.7 13.7 14.2 13.7 14.2 14 13 14.7 ...
> str(GR_02GA003)
'data.frame':   45453 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 38879 levels "1913-07-22","1913-07-23",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 02GA003: num  5.24 4.53 3.82 4.19 3.82 3.68 4.19 3.96 3.82 3.34 ...
```

What I would like:

```
Date 02GB001 02GA003
2019-12-26   0.386   0.802
2019-12-27   0.398   0.817
2019-12-28   0.459   0.899
2019-12-29   0.593   0.943
2019-12-30   0.805   1.279
2019-12-31   1.095   1.461
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RdRJnUNdUER5QXf6bsxQNyLW_Cc8aqVz/view?usp=sharing) is my data, I have tried multiple times and getting the same incorrect result. My original post is already using the only suggested answer.

Comment: Please reopen, I have included all 11 lines of code I use to reproduce these results, as well as a link to the data used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the uploaded data I can suggest this. You have sometimes more than 1 record per day (see `df1` in example below) then, when you merge your dataframes using the option `all = TRUE` these are kept and the value of the corresponding record from `df2` is duplicated

```
# df1 has two records (or two lines) the 1999/01/01
df1 = data.frame(Date = c(as.Date('1999/01/01'),seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/15'), by="day")),
                 var1 = c(1:16))
df2 = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/15'), by="day"),
                 var2 = runif(15))
df_all = merge(df1, df2, by = "Date", all = T) # both records from df1 1999/01/01 are still there and the related value from df2 is duplicated
```

OLD ANSWER

I have tried to copy your problem but I had not such issue.
Please consider this reproducible example:

```
# Ex datasets with 5 days in common
df1 = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/15'), by="day"),
                var1 = runif(15))
df2 = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('1999/01/10'), as.Date('1999/01/30'), by="day"),
                 var2 = runif(21))
# merging by dates I get the expected output with df1 and df2
df_merge = merge(df1, df2, by = "Date", all = T)

# merging with dataframes having the same set of dates
df3 = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/15'), by="day"),
                 var3 = runif(15))
df_merge2 = merge(df1, df3, by = "Date", all = T)
```

Here is the output; as expected we have 30 and 15 lines and `NA` when necessary.

```
> str(df_merge)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "1999-01-01" "1999-01-02" "1999-01-03" "1999-01-04" ...
 $ var1: num  0.0646 0.7934 0.6965 0.1142 0.0527 ...
 $ var2: num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
> str(df_merge2)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "1999-01-01" "1999-01-02" "1999-01-03" "1999-01-04" ...
 $ var1: num  0.0646 0.7934 0.6965 0.1142 0.0527 ...
 $ var3: num  0.000744 0.350087 0.429771 0.18886 0.484449 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this is how it is intended to work, but I cannot get it to with my data. I attached a link to my data if you would like to view it. I am still unable to get this to merge properly.

Comment: I am working on your data, it seems you have multiple record per day. Look at `length(unique(GR_02GB001$Date))` and to `length(GR_02GB001$Date)`.

Comment: @Jason let me know if the updated answer helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see that problem now. This helped a lot